# How can I pass a string(10000 records from a file) with single and double quotes to a mysql query?

Tags: mysql, c

I have a file with 10000 records, I am parsing each and every line and store them in different variables. I am using C on linux(gcc) to parse the file. I have to pass these to mysql db. I have a number of strings which are having both single and double quotes. An example string is shown below.

```
 YOUNGS BEARS RID'N FISH 6.5"
```

How can I pass strings like this to mysql query? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to your new friend [`mysql_real_escape_string `](https://github.com/hholzgra/connector-c-examples/blob/master/mysql_real_escape_string.c). As a note using the C API is extremely ugly, so if you have *any* other option I'd recommend that.

Comment: *How* are you passing the strings?  As part of an `insert` statement?  If so, use prepared statements, rather than trying to build a SQL statement dynamically.  IIRC, if you use a [prepared statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/c-api-prepared-statements.html), you should *not* escape the string.

Comment: Hi @JohnBode I am very new to SQL(mysql). I am totally unaware of what you are saying. But I can say I am using insert and update commands to load the data into the DB.

Comment: Thank you @tadman the link you mentioned is very useful.

Comment: @tadman It is working, but mysql_real_escape_string is adding \n to each string, so that a new line comes into picture in DB(which I don't want). How to resolve it?

Comment: You have a newline in your input data, obviously. Get rid of them.

Comment: Okay got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use a [prepared statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/c-api-prepared-statements.html) and then [bind](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-stmt-bind-param.html) each input string as necessary.  This method is faster and more secure than building the entire query dynamically, *and* you don't have to escape the input string.

You basically set up the query *once*, then execute it repeatedly, just updating the data that's being inserted.  Quick, very dirty, *very* untested example:

```
/**
 * Items read from input file (assuming they're all strings; substitute
 * with your actual data items)
 */
char itemA[ITEM_A_LENGTH];
unsigned long str_length_A;
char itemB[ITEM_B_LENGTH];
unsigned long str_length_B;
...    
MYSQL *connection;
...
const char *stmt_text = "INSERT INTO table_name VALUES( ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )"; // assumes 5 inputs
MYSQL_STMT *stmt = mysql_stmt_init( connection );
MYSQL_BIND insert_variables[5]; // assumes 5 inputs
...
int status = mysql_stmt_prepare( stmt, stmt_text, strlen( stmt_text ) );
if ( status )
{
  /**
   * Bind each input data item to the ? wildcards in the statement
   */
  insert_variables[0].buffer_type = MSQL_TYPE_STRING;
  insert_variables[0].buffer = itemA;
  insert_variables[0].buffer_length = ITEM_A_SIZE;
  insert_variables[0].is_null = 0;
  insert_variables[0].length = &str_length_A;

  /**
   * Repeat for each input item
   */
}
else
  // bail out here
...
/**
 * Read each line of input and insert into the database
 * using the prepared statement
 */
while ( fscanf( input, "%s %s %s %s %s", itemA, itemB, itemC, itemD, itemE ) == 5 )
{
  str_length_A = strlen( itemA );
  str_length_B = strlen( itemB );
  ...
  int rows_inserted = mysql_stmt_execute( insert_stmt );
  if ( rows_inserted != 1 )
  {
    // insert failed, bail out here.
  }
}
```

Like I said, this method is faster (only parses the statement once) and more secure (less surface area for a SQL injection attack) than building the entire query string dynamically.  Tradeoff is that it's a bit more work.

I don't have a MySQL instance to test against, so I can't provide working example code.  There are examples [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-stmt-execute.html) and [here](http://www.kitebird.com/mysql-book/ch06-3ed.pdf), but I can't vouch for their quality.

MySQL's documentation is...not awesome, so this will probably be a bit painful.